# Multithreaded application stops after 3 days

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management, thread-safety

I am having a multi-threaded application that fetches different web pages. For this, I've devised a parent child relationship between the threads.
The parent simply takes different urls from its page and spawns new threads. These threads keep on continuously fetching the pages until the page changes. The main thread polls every 2 minutes for the changes at the main page(and creates new threads if there is any change)

Main thread algo

```
while(true){
    find_new_instances(...);
    if we get any new, then
        Thread.start(...);
    Thread.sleep(120000);
}
```

The main thread has a String arraylist that stores the url of each new thread that it creates. I've heard that threads should only use immutable objects for writes. Is the used of mutable list here causing problems ?
In the child thread, activities such as page fetch and database inserts take place.

However, the application gradually increases its memory requirements and eventually deadlocks/starves into a frozen state or OutOfMemory if the no. of threads are too large.
I am at loss to try out anything. If you have experienced similar problems, kindly suggest.

Comment: What is the thread count? This loop will create lots of threads in the very short time and put each of them to sleep for a very long time. It does not have much sense to me...

Comment: @Random: thread count is around 50 (others are created and destroyed)

Comment: @nos: No data sharing is done between the threads, only the parent/master thread keeps a count of the running threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar type of issue while I was developing a GUI based application.

**Reasons of crashing**

- Create a Thread Pool. use the
  available thread in you application.
  You cannot create infinite thread
  that will cause crash in your
  application
- May be you are creating new
  objects(or string) and storing the
  data if possible use the same object
  assign the value. If the data is long
  you can store in file or database.
  rather than holding the data always

Comment: I am not using pooling at the moment, but would try that out. Also, should I stop the threads directly or let them sleep and continue iteratively until their work gets over? The data is getting stored in the database(this is not an issue as it has been tested separately)

Comment: As I have stated, its highly unlikely that using a Thread Pool will avoid a memory leak, but it is a good idea all the same.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your problem right then you can bypasse the OutOfMemory error by setting the old threads value to null and preforming a gc()

Comment: After profiling, I have resolved the memory problem, but the memory requirements still keep on increasing (from 20mb initially to ~250 mb after a day of running)

Comment: If the memory used continues to expand, you still have some kind of resource leak, memory, threads, handles, something is being allocated and never disposed of when you are done with it. 

Comment: It depends a lot on where the memory is going.  Is the memory being stored in short or long term heap storage or (although less likely) is it being stored in perm gen?  If you have -Xmx to say 256mb or some other large number, it will often increase without doing any drastic garbage collection so a lot of the used memory could be trash.

Answer (score 0):

You have a memory leak. I suggest you take a heap dump when you run out of memory and analyse it to see where the leak is.

To trigger a heap dump automatically, you can use the option

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

and perhaps

```
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/heap/dumps
```

If you want a pool of worker threads, I suggest you use an ExecutorService or even a ScheduledExecutorService to perform a task at a regular interval. (However this is unlikely to be you problem)